# camera_aravis (Unrecognized image encoding) with colour camera

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I try to run the camera_aravis package with aravis version 0.6 to see the raw image of a manta G-235c camera.
Wen i run the rqt image view i get the following error: ImageView.callback_image() while trying to convert image from 'BayerRG8' to 'rgb8' an exception was thrown (Unrecognized image encoding [BayerRG8]).
I can change the pixel format with the aravis viewer, but this only change the 'BayerRG8' to a other type of file in the error messages.
The only format that works with the rqt viewer is the Mono8 format, but this turns the image black and white.

Does anyone have a idea how to solve this, so i can use the colour images?

On my system i run Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.
The camera_aravis package i cloned from this: git https://github.com/takiaine/camera_aravis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312893/camera_aravis-(unrecognized-image-encoding)-with-colour-camera/) by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a solution for my problem.

Instead of using the camera_aravis package for the manta G-235c camera, the prosilica_camera will work.
The camera_aravis package publish the pixel format of the camera, instead of a base pixel format (like rgb8).
So if the pixel format is rgb8packed (or BayerRG8 for the manta G-235c), the camera_aravis will send that type of pixel format.
The prosilica_camera package will translate the pixel format of the camera to rgb8 pixel format.

The prosilica_camera is not directly usable with software that is written with a universal camera package in mind.
Before using it you need to solve this problem: https://answers.ros.org/question/280342/issues-with-prosilica-camera-connected-through-router/.
After that you need to remove **_drivers** text in the generic.launch file and add **camera/** to the raw_image publisher in the prosilica_nodelet.cpp.

---

Originally posted by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) with karma: 15 on 2019-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0